# Python Pandas find element in a list

Tags: python, list, pandas

I created two list from pandas dataframe as follows:-

**List1**: was created from multiple csv files within a folder as seen below...

```html
import glob as gb
csv_files = gb.glob("csv\\*.csv")

# csv_files = csv_files[0:]

# Create list of the CSV in dataframes
dfList = []
for file in csv_files:
    df_csv = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    dfList.append(df_csv)    

# print (dfList)

# Convert each dataframe within the list into individual list
new_dfList = []
for ind_df in dfList:
    # Convert the dataframe to a list
    new_convert = ind_df.values.tolist()
    new_dfList.append(new_convert)
```

**List2**: was created from a text file that contain keywords as seen below.

```html
# Open keywords TEXT file
keywords = pd.read_csv("words.txt", header=None)

# Convert the dataframe to a list
keywords = keywords.values.tolist()

# Move out from inner list
# keywords = list(chain(*keywords))

# print (keywords)
keywords[0]
```

These keywords from list2 are to be compared with each list in list1. How do I do it?

How do I make the first keyword (in list2) goto first list (in list1), second keyword (in list2) goto second list (in list1), third keyword (in list2) goto third list (in list1)....and so on to search and return a match result?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do it in pandas?

```
keywords = pd.read_csv("words.txt", header=None)

dfList = []
for file in csv_files:
    df_csv = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    dfList.append(df_csv)

df = pd.concat(dfList, keys=keywords)
# Or, make a panel
wp = pd.Panel(dict(zip(keywords, dfList)))
# Or, just leave it as a dictionary
df_dict = dict(zip(keywords, dfList))
```

And if you really want a dictionary of lists:

```
df_dict_list = dict(zip(keywords, [df.tolist() for df in dfList]))
```